# Matlab: repmat code explanation

Tags: matlab, histogram

Can anyone explain the two lines of code highlighted below which use `repmat`? This is taken directly from the MathWorks [documentation for learning data analysis](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/data-analysis.html):

```
bin_counts = hist(c3);  % Histogram bin counts
N = max(bin_counts);    % Maximum bin count
mu3 = mean(c3);         % Data mean
sigma3 = std(c3);       % Data standard deviation

hist(c3) % Plot histogram
hold on
plot([mu3 mu3],[0 N],'r','LineWidth',2) % Mean
% --------------------------------------------------------------
X = repmat(mu3+(1:2)*sigma3,2,1);       % WHAT IS THIS?
Y = repmat([0;N],1,2);                  % WHY IS THIS NECESSARY?
% --------------------------------------------------------------
plot(X,Y,'g','LineWidth',2) % Standard deviations
legend('Data','Mean','Stds')
hold off
```

Could anyone explain the `X = repmat(...)` line to me? I know it will be plotted for the 1 and 2 standard deviation lines.

Also, I tried commenting out the `Y = ...` line, and the plot looks the exact same, so what is the purpose of this line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break the expression into multiple statements

```
X = repmat(mu3+(1:2)*sigma3,2,1);
```

is equivalent to

```
% First create a row vector containing one and two standard deviations from the mean.
% This is equivalent to xvals = [mu3+1*sigma3, mu3+2*sigma3];
xval = mu3 + (1:2)*sigma3;

% Repeat the matrix twice in the vertical dimension. We want to plot two vertical
% lines so the first and second point should be equal so we just use repmat to repeat them.
% This is equivalent to
% X = [xvals;
%      xvals];
X = repmat(xval,2,1);

% To help understand how repmat works, if we had X = repmat(xval,3,2) we would get
% X = [xval, xval;
%      xval, xval;
%      xval, xval];
```

The logic is similar for the `Y` matrix except it repeats in the column direction. Together you end up with

```
X = [mu3+1*sigma3, mu3+2*sigma3;
     mu3+1*sigma3, mu3+2*sigma3];
Y = [0, 0;
     N, N];
```

When plot is called it plots one line per column of the `X` and `Y` matrices.

```
plot(X,Y,'g','LineWidth',2);
```

is equivalent to

```
plot([mu3+1*sigma3; mu3+1*sigma3], [0, N], 'g','LineWidth',2);
hold on;
plot([mu3+2*sigma3; mu3+2*sigma3], [0, N], 'g','LineWidth',2);
```

which plots two vertical lines, one and two standard deviations from the mean.

If you comment out `Y` then `Y` isn't defined. The reason the code still worked is probably that the previous value of `Y` was still stored in the workspace. If you run the command `clear` before running the script again you will find that the `plot` command will fail.